# Segmented Key Subaccount of PrepaymentSubID do not exist in the system

Tags: acumatica

After authenticating, trying to use any REST API endpoints, returns the following error:

```
/SalesOrder
------------
Method: GET
URL: http://my.domain/entity/Default/17.200.001/SalesOrder
Response Code: 500

Response
--------
{
"message": "An error has occurred.",
"exceptionMessage": "Error: Warehouse, Family, Class, Procedence, Department, Available of PrepaymentSubID do not exist in the system.",
"exceptionType": "PX.Data.PXSetPropertyException",
"stackTrace": "   at PX.Data.PXDimensionSelectorAttribute.FieldVerifying(PXCache sender, PXFieldVerifyingEventArgs e)\r\n   at PX.Data.PXCache.OnFieldVerifying(String name, Object row, Object& newValue, Boolean externalCall)\r\n   at PX.Data.PXSelectorAttribute.SubstituteKeyFieldUpdating(PXCache sender, PXFieldUpdatingEventArgs e)\r\n   at PX.Data.PXSelectorAttribute.SubstituteKeyFieldUpdating(PXCache sender, PXFieldUpdatingEventArgs e)\r\n   at PX.Data.PXDimensionSelectorAttribute.FieldUpdating(PXCache sender, PXFieldUpdatingEventArgs e)\r\n   at PX.Data.PXCache.OnFieldUpdating(String name, Object row, Object& newValue)\r\n   at PX.Data.PXCache`1.SetValueExt(Object data, String fieldName, Object value)\r\n   at PX.Objects.GL.SubAccountAttribute.SetSubAccount(PXCache sender, Object row)\r\n   at PX.Data.PXCache.OnRowInserting(Object item, Boolean externalCall)\r\n   at PX.Data.PXCache`1.Insert(Object data, Boolean bypassinterceptor)\r\n   at PX.Data.PXCache`1.Insert(Object data, Boolean bypassinterceptor)\r\n   at PX.Data.PXCache`1.Insert(Object data)\r\n   at PX.Data.PXCache`1.Insert()\r\n   at PX.Data.PXFilter`1.a()\r\n   at PX.Data.PXGraph.GetDefault[TNode]()\r\n   at PX.Data.PXCache`1.get_Current()\r\n   at PX.Data.PXDefaultAttribute.FieldDefaulting(PXCache sender, PXFieldDefaultingEventArgs e)\r\n   at PX.Data.PXCache.OnFieldDefaulting(String name, Object row, Object& newValue)\r\n   at PX.Data.PXView.PrepareParametersInternal(Object[] currents, Object[] parameters, IBqlParameter[] selpars)\r\n   at PX.Data.PXView.Select(Object[] currents, Object[] parameters, Object[] searches, String[] sortcolumns, Boolean[] descendings, PXFilterRow[] filters, Int32& startRow, Int32 maximumRows, Int32& totalRows)\r\n   at PX.Data.PXView.SelectMultiBound(Object[] currents, Object[] parameters)\r\n   at PX.Data.PXSelectorAttribute.SelectSingleBound(PXView view, Object[] currents, Object[] pars)\r\n   at PX.Data.PXSelectorAttribute.GetItem(PXCache cache, PXSelectorAttribute attr, Object data, Object key, Boolean unconditionally)\r\n   at PX.Data.PXSelectorAttribute.<>c__DisplayClass118_0.<Select>b__0(PXSelectorAttribute attr)\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n   at PX.Data.Selector`2.Verify(PXCache cache, Object item, List`1 pars, Nullable`1& result, Object& value)\r\n   at PX.Data.BqlFunction.getValue[Operand](IBqlCreator& op, PXCache cache, Object item, List`1 pars, Nullable`1& result, Object& value)\r\n   at PX.Data.Case2`2.Verify(PXCache cache, Object item, List`1 pars, Nullable`1& result, Object& value)\r\n   at PX.Data.Switch`2.Verify(PXCache cache, Object item, List`1 pars, Nullable`1& result, Object& value)\r\n   at PX.Data.BqlFormula.Verify(PXCache cache, Object item, IBqlCreator formula, Nullable`1& result, Object& value)\r\n   at PX.Data.PXFormulaAttribute.FormulaDefaulting(PXCache sender, PXFieldDefaultingEventArgs e)\r\n   at PX.Data.PXFormulaAttribute.SetFormulaValue(PXCache sender, Object row)\r\n   at PX.Data.PXFormulaAttribute.<>c__DisplayClass58_0.<CacheAttached>b__1(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectingEventArgs e)\r\n   at PX.Data.PXRowSelecting.Invoke(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectingEventArgs e)\r\n   at PX.Data.PXCache.OnRowSelecting(Object item, PXDataRecord record, Int32& position, Boolean isReadOnly)\r\n   at PX.Api.ContractBased.OptimizedExport.OptimizedExportProvider.ExtractValues(BqlCommand command, PXDataRecord r, PXDataRecordMap map, Dictionary`2 previousRow)\r\n   at PX.Api.ContractBased.OptimizedExport.OptimizedExportProvider.<DoDbSelect>d__44.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()\r\n   at PX.Api.ContractBased.OptimizedExport.OptimizedExportProvider.<DoSelectImpl>d__42.MoveNext()\r\n   at PX.Api.ContractBased.ExportTableToEntitiesMapperBase.<ReadEntityRowsImpl>d__24.MoveNext()\r\n   at PX.Api.ContractBased.ExportTableToEntitiesMapperBase.<ReadEntityRows>d__23.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n   at PX.Api.ContractBased.EntityService.GetListOptimized(EntityImpl entity, EntityExportContextBuilder entityExportContextBuilder, IOptimizedExportProviderForContractBased provider, String version, String name, String objectName, ISystemContract systemContract)\r\n   at PX.Api.ContractBased.EntityService.GetList(ISystemContract systemContract, String version, String name, EntityImpl entity, Boolean returnFullEntities, CbOperationContext operationContext, Boolean ignoreValueFields, PXGraph graph)\r\n   at PX.Api.ContractBased.Soap.SoapFacadeBase.GetListImpl(Entity entity, Boolean returnFullEntities)\r\n   at PX.Api.ContractBased.SystemContracts.V2.RestController.GetList(String objectName, String select, String filter, String expand, String custom, Nullable`1 skip, Nullable`1 top)\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()"
}
```

What is PrepaymentSubID and how is it related to the Segmented Keys? I can't find any relation at all.

Comment: This is unexpected. How was configuration data populated in that instance? I would think your question is missing some elements. For example you are talking about segmented keys but nowhere in the URL or error message you provided is segmented key mentioned. Also is that really how the error messages are displayed or did you reformat them differently when posting the question?

Comment: Warehouse, Family, Class, Procedence, Department, Available are the values of teh sgmented key code SUBACCOUNT. About the configuration, there's a company that is configuring the instance but they know nothing about the API or the database. Let me update the error message.

Comment: Thanks for updating the error message. As I suspected you previously had two errors conflated in one. After the edit one error has disappeared 'An error occurred during processing of the field Workgroup:'. Was that error relevant to the SalesOrder get call?

Comment: The "Error: An error occurred during processing of the field Workgroup" was part of the message error when trying to get the detail of a sales order. I can add it if you want.

Comment: Please don't, it just add confusion. You can ask a second question for details and add relevant message for that one. Do you have access to the website instance through web browser? My first advice would be to play a little bit with the Sales Order screen (create sales order, navigate to sales order, create shipment etc...) to make sure it is properly configured.

Comment: Yes, I have access. Everything is working correctly (users are being trained on how to use the the system)

Comment: The error message suggests there is corrupted data in database. The REST command is for getting all sales order. As a test to see if all or only a handful of sales order fail. Please use the '/ordertype/ordernbr' method suggested in the following URL to retrieve single order. Please try a few of them that have different customer on sales order. Do not put the expand details part though. https://stackoverflow.com/a/42852601/7376238

Comment: This is weird. The session expired and when i authenticated again, it started working fine. Maybe it was an issue with the authentication? Another topic, is there a website or documentation where i can read a more detailed information about the API? I'm having a hard time trying to use the API to create orders.

Comment: I210 training guide in Acumatica university: https://openuni.acumatica.com/courses/

Comment: My general approach to creating records using API is to first do a get on an entity (without expand details) to get the JSON format down. After that I keep only the entity key fields (OrderType, OrderNbr, Customer etc..) and the other fields that I want to populate. After that I change the GET request to a POST request.

Comment: oh and I posted an answer regarding why your API calls worked after the session expired

Comment: Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a glitch. Maybe some unexpected/malformed API call resulted in an error that stuck around in subsequent calls due to a bug in Acumatica API.

What you can do to get out of that corrupted state is restart the application. This can be done on the web server using IISReset command in admin command prompt or through the web site UI with RESTART APPLICATION button on Apply Updates page:
[image]

Comment: Another hypothesis could be that you logged into the wrong company which happened to be not properly configured but this is less likely.